# Can the user of proftpd change the password themself not by admin?

Tags: proftpd

I have read all the command on ftp which contains no command to change passwd.
I am a user of proftpd ,how can change my password after logining into proftpd by myself not by admin?
User can change it's own password in ssh service ,not by admin,it is convenient.

Comment: This question is not directly about programming, but rather about networking software and belongs at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com). =)

Answer (score 6):

As far as i know ProFTPD does not contain its own users, but rather uses external resources to authenticate. That means that if you want to edit a user (or it's password) you need to edit whatever source ProFTPD authenticated that user against (i.e. /etc/passwd, PAM, LDAP, etc).

This, unfortunately for you, means that you can not edit your password from within an FTP session, but rather have to access the server via SSH or similar to change it.

More info can be found in the documentation: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Authentication.html